# Use of forName and GetClassLoader

Tags: java

When I read the documentation about `Class`, as to `forName()` method, the documentation said:

```
Class.forName ("Foo")
```

is equivalent to:

```
Class.forName ("Foo", true, this.getClass().GetClassLoader())
```

I don't know what the meaning of `this.getClass().GetClassLoader()` and why it works in this way, I just know it is a ClassLoader to load class when JVM complier the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ClassLoader is an object capable of loading bytecode as a class into the VM. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) for the offical docs.

`Class.forName(String name)` allows you to load a class at runtime - the supplied String can by determined at runtime. To actually load a class one needs a ClassLoader thus it was chosen that the ClassLoader the class of the calling object was loaded with is the default one. You access that ClassLoader with `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`.

The second parameter - defaulting to `true` - determines if static intialization is performed for the class if necessary (if it hasn't been performed earlier).

Answer (score 0):

class.forName returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name. Invoking this method is equivalent to:

```
Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)
```

where currentLoader denotes the defining class loader of the current class.